# Problem while using Extended ASCII Values

Tags: c#, hardware, plc

I am doing a project with a PLC, im using sockets to interact with server listening on the PLC.I gave the instructions in the ASCII Format,untill 127 my instructions are working fine,when it exceeds 127 ,the code works but proper values are not sent to the PLC . how to overcome this.

s= 130;

Query = Convert.ToChar(00).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(00).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(00).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(00).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(00).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(06).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(01).ToString(); // Headder
                    Query = Query + Convert.ToChar(06).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(AddrUB).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(AddrLB).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(valueUB).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(s).ToString() ;

after converting it to char s becomes a special symbol,instead of writing 130 in the plc
the query write it as 63, whats happening in the conversion,please help me to solve this

Comment: Give an example, what is sent to PLC, and what does PLC receive.

Comment: You gave the code, fine, but could you give us an example of the actual string of bytes that are being sent to PLC, and actual string of bytes that PLC actually sees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII 63 is question mark. The main reason of some character above 127 to turn into question mark is conversion from one code page to another that does not support the character in question. So basically there is some conversion happening.

The solution is not to work with strings. PLC understands bytes, so you should work with byte arrays, not strings. Keep in mind that chars are not bytes in C# world.

Comment: hi dialecticus, thanks for your reply but i already found this on the day itself i asked the question ,anyway thank you very much